# Is it possible to get column format through a PDO OCI query in php?

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oracle-call-interface

in php5,
i have an oracle query .. let's say

```
select month,max(mydate) as maxdate,sum(cash) as total_cash from mytable group by month
```

i would like, through PDO OCI, to format a table according to the type of each column

month=varchar
maxdate=date
total_cash=number

is there a way to obtain the column types from Oracle ?  as my query can be changed, i can't look in oracle system table to get the type : columns can be calculations or concatenations of columns

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official way to do this in PDO is calling [`PDOStatement::getColumnMeta()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) after performing a query.  Call it once per column in the result set, where column zero is the first.

It requires driver support, though, and I can't vouch for the Oracle driver.

Comment: oh great, i had not seen that, thanks, i need to check but i think nothing can be better with using PDO

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, there are system views that will allow you to query for this information.

```
SELECT column_name, data_type FROM dba_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'mytable';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have limited privileges in an Oracle database you can still find the datatypes by querying

```
select owner, table_name, column_name, data_type, data_length, data_precision, data_scale, nullable
 from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'MYTABLE';
```

There are more columns of interest in that view, for example last_analyzed and other values used as input for the optimizer.